# Contribution custom field not appearing in New Contribution window

Tags: civicontribute, custom-fields

We are planning on migrating from our current membership database to CiviCRM. I am starting to experiment with the system to see how to implement things.
I am using version 4.7.17 on WordPress. 
We want to specify whether a mailed donation came to the station or to our PO Box. I set up a custom data field for contributions (alphanumeric text). 
It's active and searchable but when I go to the New Contribution window, it doesn't appear. 
Have I missed something ?

(I know alphanumeric text may not be the best choice, but for now I simply want to figure out why it is not appearing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you make a Custom Field on Contribution of type -any- or did you narrow it down to specific financial type(s)? If that's the case you must select the Type first when entering a new Contribution - to make the Field appear;

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you.  I expect to be asking a number of "easy" questions as I am just starting to work with CiviCRM

Comment: This is a good place to do so - and also a good place to search if you run into any issues.